# Registering a different implementation of a service dependant on httpcontext in multi-tenant application Hangfire

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, hangfire

I have a multi-tenant application where applications are connected to different databases. The application identifies relevant tenants using a connection hash. the connection hash comes from the request header. since HTTPContext is not serializing in Hangifre I need to find a way to pass the connection hash when the service (Repositories) registers.

I was thinking of adding JobFilterAttribute to pass hash information lying below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TenantResolverAttribute : JobFilterAttribute
{

}

public class TenantResolverFilter : IClientFilter, IServerFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TenantResolverFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
        var hash = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetCurrentTenantDatabaseHash();
        filterContext.SetJobParameter("hash", hash);

    }

    public void OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        var hash = filterContext.GetJobParameter<string>("hash");
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

}
```

But the problem is how to pass this information to a method where the entity framework to configure

```
  string conenctionString = //need to resolve conenction string using provided hash;
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conenctionString,
        option =>
        {
            option.CommandTimeout(config.SqlCommandTimeout);
            option.EnableRetryOnFailure(3);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get hash from httpcontext like this.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, dbContextBuilder) =>
{
    var hash = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetCurrentTenantDatabaseHash();

    // here you can resolve your connection string using hash and use it.
    var connectionString = 
    dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```